# Close or load a blank page after middle-click on tab in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Using a stock Firefox install of 3.6.6 install, there's no close button if there is only one tab open.  Here's the current behavior when I **middle-click on that tab**:

- nothing happens

Here's the behavior I *want* when I **middle-click** on that tab:

- web page disappears
- same tab remains, but it's now blank

How can I make Firefox behave this way?  I've had it before, but I don't know if it was an addon (likely TabMix Plus) or a tweak I made to the stock browser?

I really want this without installing addons, but I accept that an addon may be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In about:config, set

> browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab

to false.

Edit: This works on my iMac; doesn't on my macbook. No idea what's different, YMMV.

Comment: This does not put a close button on the tab.  It does allow me to close the tab w/ a middle click (which flashes a close button on the tab, for an instant, as it's closing).  When the tab closes, a blank tab immediately replaces it.  The browser does not close.  That'll do until I can get TabMixPlus.

Comment: In Preferences | Tabs, unticking "Always show the tab bar" will allow that only remaining tab to actually go away.
Close-buttons are controlled by another about:config variable, "browser.tabs.closeButtons".  This page in Mozilla's Knowlegebase describes the possible values and their behaviors: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.tabs.closeButtons .

Answer (score 0):

Tab mix plus does this, but you have to do a little tweak to it go to Tab Mix Plus Options -> Events -> Tab Closing -> Closing Last tab, and check "Do not close window when closing last tab".

EDIT: There is no way to do this without tab mix plus.